# Mysql query: Add X day to current date

Tags: mysql

I have actually this query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(`expiry_date`,INTERVAL 7 DAY), '%d.%m.%Y' )
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `user_id` = '[user_id]';
```

This was planned for add 7 days to expiry_date field stored in user account. Now I need to fork this query and instead to get expiry_date I need to get current date (today date). Then instead to add 7 days I need to add the number of day present in the field allowed_days.

I make some test, but I'm a sql newbie and I afraid to broke my database. If somebody could help...Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is just a slight variation on your query.  Because you are a newbie . . .

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL allowed_days DAY), '%d.%m.%Y' )
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `user_id` = '[user_id]';
```

Comment: you rock! That was not as difficult as I thought